# Returning data from function in Firebase observer code block swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm new to firebase and I want to know if is any possible way to return data in observer block. I have class `ApiManager:NSObject` and in this class I want to create all my firebase function that will return some kind of data from database. This is one of my function in this class

```
    func downloadDailyQuote() -> [String:String] {

    let reference = Database.database().reference().child("daily")

    reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap) in
        return snap.value as! [String:String] //I want to return this
    }


    return ["":""] //I don't want to return this
}
```

And if I now do something like `let value = ApiManager().downloadDailyQuote()`, `value` contains empty dictionary. Is any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** When you call .observeSingleEvent, you call the method asynchronously. This means that the method will start working, but the response will come later and will not block the main thread. You invoke this method, but there is no data yet and therefore you return an empty dictionary.

If you use the completion block, then you will get the data as soon as the method action is completed.

```
func downloadDailyQuote(completion: @escaping ([String:String]) -> Void) {
   let reference = Database.database().reference().child("daily")

   reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap) in

      if let dictionaryWithData = snap.value as? [String:String] {
         completion(dictionaryWithData) 
      } else {
         completion(["" : ""])
      }        
    }
 }
```